# Why would background: url() redirect to the image?

Tags: css, struts2, sitemesh

I'm using Struts2 w/ SiteMesh.  In my CSS I have the following line:

```
#top_nav {
    background: url('../images/menu_tile.png') repeat-x 0 0 ;
    height: 36px; 
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

When I login to the site my browser gets redirected to /url/menu_tile.png.  The only place I can find menu_tile.png in my site is in a css file that is part of my sitemesh decorator.

If I use my browser back button and login a 2nd time I get sent to the correct page.  If I remove the background: from my CSS and login fresh I also get sent to the right page (but obviously my page is wrong).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: this is confusing. Are you saying that when log in, your browser redirects you to the location of the image, or are you saying the request for the image is redirected?

Comment: @orokusaki - Updated.  Thanks for pointing out the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traced the problem down to the following...

```
...
<title>My Site/title>
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The missing < for the title tag for some reason said to the browser... load the next url() as a page?

*sigh*

Comment: very strange. These type of "features" cost thousands of hours of folks' time.

Comment: Follow up -- The problem came back!  I found the actual problem had to do with SiteMesh & spring security.  My SiteMesh template wanted to provide access to the graphics but spring security was requiring authentication to that image so I think when I hit the login page it tried to load an image for the page.  It couldn't so it requested I authenticate but tracked that specific image as what I was trying to access before login.